# Deserialization of Object serialized by @JsonIdentityInfo

Tags: java, android, spring, jackson

I am having my User class annotated like this to remove cyclic format of output:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = User.class)
public class User extends AbstractValueObject {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
 .....
}

public class Load extends AbstractValueObject {
    private Integer id;
    private User postedBy;
}
```

So whenever i fetch List of Load it is giving me output as below JSON :

```
[
  {
   "id" : 1,
   "postedBy" : {
                  "id":1,
                  "name":"SOF"    
                }
  },
  {
   "id" : 2,
   "postedBy" : 1
  }
]
```

But client side wants it in original format - say each object of load should contain full `postedBy` object. Client side is in Android - Java.

Is there any way at Android end to de-serialize object in original format at Android ?

Expected output :

```
   [
      {
       "id" : 1,
       "postedBy" : {
                      "id":1,
                      "name":"SOF"    
                    }
      },
      {
       "id" : 2,
       "postedBy" : {
                      "id":1,
                      "name":"SOF"    
                    }
      }
    ]
```

I tried with JSOG but in some cases it fails.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: put your expected json format in the question.

Comment: Have updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jsog Converter, which provide library to encode and decode objects.
https://github.com/jsog/jsog